# How to use Evolutions in Play Framework 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

For play 1.x, we can use `play evolutions:apply`, How can I do it in play-2.0-beta?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Evolution:apply is run automatically upon application start up. What is missing in Play 2.0-rc1 is a way to generate the evolutions scripts, and to manually apply them from the SBT console.

But here is how to create them manually.

Say you have the following definition in `application.conf`

```
db.mydb.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.mydb.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play
```

Play2 will look for evolution in the following folder: `application/db/evolutions/mydb/`
In this folder, evolutions shall be stored as sql file, using the evolution step as the file name.

For instance:

```
application/db/evolutions/mydb/1.sql
application/db/evolutions/mydb/2.sql
application/db/evolutions/mydb/3.sql
```

Now the sql itself has the following structure:

```
# --- !Ups
create table company (
  id                        bigint not null,
  name                      varchar(255),
  constraint pk_company primary key (id));
# --- !Downs
drop table if exists company;
```

**!Ups** are used to upgrade the model to the next evolutions
**!Downs** are used to revert the *!Ups*

Like I said in the intro, evolutions will be magically applied upon application startup.

Comment: And how do I apply those to a unit test? My tests fail all because play complains about missing evolutions.

Comment: @Jan if using play 2.0's specs2, you can run the evolutions with: running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {
       // blah blah
}

Comment: i hate magic... right now the magic isn't working and it'd be very helpful if i could manually trigger the evolutions... OH! just figured, my 2.sql had a SQL error and the evolution was just being ignored!

Comment: its only automatic for prod application, you have to apply manually for dev i believe.