# Running evolutions on Play Framework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

This recent post, [How to use Evolutions in Play Framework 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164157/how-to-use-evolutions-in-play-framework-2-0), says that evolutions will automatically be applied when running Play 2.0.  I've tried the play-2.0-beta download and latest git code, and I'm not seeing this behavior.  In fact, I can't find any way to apply the evolutions in production mode.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding about the sentence "evolutions are automatically activated". This sentence is in the context of "You can disable them by setting evolutionplugin=disabled". Activated doesn't mean "automatically applied".   I certainly suffered from this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Adding `applyEvolutions.default=true` to your application.conf will enable evolutions by default in your application.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be necessary...  The documentation for version 2.0.3 (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Evolutions) indicates, "evolutions are automatically activated" and "Play will check your database schema state before each request in DEV mode"...  Unless the above is only relevant in `PROD` mode (??).  But the documentation doesn't seem to mention this config parameter at all.

Comment: This was necessary for Play 2.0.2, not sure about 2.0.3

Comment: I am using Play 2.2.x and starting an application with % play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true which works perfectly.

Comment: On Play 2.4+: play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true

Comment: How enable evolutions for tests with spec2 ?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding about the sentence "evolutions are automatically activated".  This sentence is in the context of "You can disable them by setting evolutionplugin=disabled".  Activated doesn't mean "automatically applied".

Answer (score 3):

Please try one of the Play 20 sample applications and you will be prompted to apply evolutions upon application startup - the request appears in the application browser the first time you start the app.

Comment: That works in dev mode, but if I run the samples in production mode, I immediately get the following exception:Oops, cannot start the server.
play.api.db.evolutions.InvalidDatabaseRevision: Database 'default' needs evolution! [An SQL script need to be run on your database.]

Comment: good point, looks like something that needs to be implemented in a near future. you can still start it in dev, apply the evolution and then switch to prod. But I agree, it should work as play 1.0

Answer (score 3):

As of RC-3, the new location of the evolutions scripts is in conf/evolutions/[dbname]/1.sql. Otherwise, the information above is all still accurate.